# MS Excel: Creating a box and whisker plot from organized data

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

Excel 2016 seems to expect data for box and whisker plots as two columns, one for the category and one for the values:

```
Horror 27
Action 24
Horror 56
Romance 92
...
```

I'd like to give the data from a categorized table:

```
Horror Action Romance ...
27     24      92
56
...
```

Of course, I only have one series. I know I can transform the table into two columns, but I would prefer a cleaner solution.